# AzureRM PowerShell: How to set a custom domain onto a web app deployment slot?

Tags: powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

So this is how I do it for a webapp

```
Set-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $WebAppName -HostNames @($Alias, $Url);
```

Which doesn't work for a slot within a web app, like so:

```
Set-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $SlotName -HostNames @($SlotAlias, $SlotUrl);
```

And fails with:

> The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/sitename-staging' under resource group 'resgrpname' was not found.

Then there is this `Set-AzureRmWebAppSlot` but it doesn't have a `-HostNames` option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on my understanding, you could leverage [Set-AzureRmResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.resources/v2.0.3/set-azurermresource) to set a custom domain for your web app deployment slot as follows:

```html
$resourceGroupName = "{your-resourcegroup-name}"
$ResourceType="Microsoft.Web/sites/slots"
$webappName="{your-webapp-name}"
$stageName="{staging-name}"

$Alias="$webappName-$stageName.azurewebsites.net"
$customDomain="{your-customdomain-for-staging}"

$hostnames=@{"hostNames"=@($Alias,$customDomain)}

Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceType $ResourceType -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceName "$webappName/$stageName" -propertyobject $hostnames -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -force
```

[image]

For `ResourceType` and `ResourceName`, you could leverage [resources.azure.com](https://resources.azure.com) as follows:

[image]

Comment: Ahh, of course. I completely overlooked that cmdlet ... and I am using it elsewhere also for another purpose. Let me try and confirm it. Thanks again